# WebDriver > switch between sibling frames

Tags: java, webdriver

I have the following HTML with frames

```
<frameset border="0" cols="*,0">
  <frame scrolling="auto" src="/cgi-bin/haipage/page.html?tpl=ntrc/index" name="smgleft">
    <html>
      <head>
    <frameset frameborder="0" border="0" rows="20%,*" cols="100%">
      <frame scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="/cgi-bin/haipage/page.html?tpl=Administration/b" name="head">
      <frame scrolling="auto" marginhei![enter image description here][1]ght="0" marginwidth="0" src="/cgi-bin/haipage/page.html" name="main">
          </html>
          </frame>
        </frameset>
    </html>
  </frame>
</frameset>
```

When I land on page I'm using

```
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("head"));
```

Since I want to access some elements under 'head' frame

Now I want to switch frame = main, so I am using

```
 driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
 driver.switchTo().frame("main");
```

but I get error message saying 'Unable to find frame'. I believe call to driver.switchTo().defaultContent() get to the top, then go down to the frame you want.

Also, when I try to find the frames after switching to the defaultContent(), I see in the logs only one frame = 'smgleft'

```
 List<WebElement> frameset = driver.findElements(By.tagName("frame"));  
   if(frameset.size()>0) {  
            for (WebElement framename : frameset)
                logger.info("frameid: " + framename.getAttribute("name"));               
            }
```

Am I missing something here? How do I switch between sibling frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember, there is no such thing called "switch between sibling frames". What you were doing should be correct in theory (except for if you want to go inside `main` from default content, you need to switch to `smgleft` first)

So have you tried

```java
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("smgleft");
// maybe some debugging here see if you can find frame "main" now
driver.switchTo().frame("main");
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked...so i have to first switch to defaultContent(), then switch to frame=smgleft and then switch to frame=main...(i cannot jump directly from defaultContent to main)....thats good to know..thanks much again...!