# Not able to switch in between frames in web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<iframe id="vacancy_department_requirements_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:""" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press ALT-F9 for menu. Press ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; display: block;">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

I am having problem in switching the iframes while automating the application using webdriver. There are three texteditor. And when I do inspect element then at the same iframe id the id changes. so I am unable to switch in between the frames.

I wrote the following code:-

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("vacancy_job_requirements_ifr"));


WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
JavascriptExecutor executor3 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor3.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '<h1>Set text using innerHTML2</h1>'", element2);
        */
        /*wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("vacancy_job_description_ifr"));

WebElement element3 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
JavascriptExecutor executor4 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor4.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '<h1>Set text using innerHTML2 gf</h1>'", element3);


        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("vacancy_department_requirements_ifr"));
 WebElement element4 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
JavascriptExecutor executor5 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor5.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '<h1>Set text using innerHTML3 gf</h1>'", element4);*/
```

But the above code is giving me following error:
`"Timed out after 120 seconds waiting for frame to be available: vacancy_job_description_ifr'`

Please suggest.

Comment: It's similar to this question, Please go through it.

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096993/webdriver-switch-between-sibling-frames

Answer (score 0):

You can switch frame by its index i.e. driver.switchTo().frame(). Find the number of frames and switch to frame by providing its index value.

Refer link ([How to switch between frames in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java))

Comment: I am a newbie to webdriver. could you plz let me know how to find index value?

Comment: Not able to switch with indexes also.

Answer (score 0):

Use driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("pvacancy_department_requirements_ifr")));